# fault-tolerant `check-parens` resp. `scan-lists`

Tags: debugging, balanced-parentheses

Looking for a way to have a fault-tolerant navigation. I.e. in case of broken syntax, uncomplete forms etc. --when
`check-paren` fails--, it should try some heuristics.

Unfortunatly can't use `check-parens` resp. `scan-lists` for branching, as these return an error, which breaks
further execution. Consider `nil` as return value in case of fail and
`some-value` in case of correctnes.

Comment: `ignore-errors`?

Comment: @npostavs Must distingish the result. Nil is already returned in case of success. A workaround will check if point moved by syntactic-sensitiv navigation.

Comment: `condition-case`+`progn` then. I guess the diificulty is in the "heuristics" though.